# C# pass a string on an onClick event of a button

Tags: c#, string, button, onclick

Ok, I am not sure how to do this as I am trying to teach myself C# and create a program for work at the same time.

I have a List of IP addresss:

```
List<IPAddress> addresses
```

I have a group of buttons being created for these ip addresses dynamically on the fly once the list is submitted to the form.

I want to pass a string of text associated to the button (the IPAddress) to the onclick event.

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "Router\n\r" + String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.126", ba[0], ba[1], ba[2]);
b.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
b.Click += btnRouter_Click;
b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 50);
tlp.Controls.Add(b, 1, 0);
```

When the button is clicked I want it to launch a command line argument to call putty.exe and go out to a version of the IP address that it was passed when this button was dynamically created, namely the x.x.x.126 address.

My onClick Stub right now is:

```
private void btnRouter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You clicked the Router button!");
}
```

what I would like is something like:

```
private void btnRouter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Putty.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments= "xxx.xxx.xx.126"
    Process.Start(myProcess.StartInfo)
}
```

Only I don't know how to get that string to the button onclick event since it isn't passes by Object or EventArgs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick solution, you could do

```
Button b = new Button();
...
b.Tag = "my string";
```

And then within the event handler

```
private void btnRouter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)((Button)sender).Tag);
}
```

---

Or, as @paqogomez suggested, you may just use`Text` value instead of using `Tag` (if you do not mind to get the address prefixed with `"Router\n\r"`:

```
private void btnRouter_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)((Button)sender).Text);
}
```

Comment: @paqogomez Yep, could be. Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @paqogomez I re-read the question, it might be that `.Text` is not exactly what PO wants due to the `"Router\n\r"` prefix.

Comment: Thanks!!!  didn't know about that b.tag.  again very new to C#.  That was exactly what I needed!